# How can I disassemble a Computar M8513 lens?

Tags: lens, diy

How can I disassemble a Computar M8513 lens?

It is a C-mount lens with a focal length of 8.5 and f1:1.3, it has manual focus and manual aperture.

The aperture/iris can be opened/closed rotating the aperture blades by rotating "1" (see the picture below). "2" is the focus and rotating "2" cause either "1" to stop at "3" or to stop at "4" and so I am stuck and I am not able to completely "unscrew" the helicoid.

Any suggestion?

[image]

**Edit**:
I have managed to disassemble the front lens:
[image]

But I have no idea on how to proceed from here:
[image]

**Conclusion**
I have finally managed to disassemble it: the crucial point was to remove thew golden ring that keeps together the three iris petals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these things have a retaining ring that holds the lens assembly into the barrel/body of the lens. If you look at the front you'll probably see a ring with a couple of slots opposite each other. This ring will unscrew (unless it's been glued in or something). When you do that the front element will most likely be removable and other elements as well. There might be a similar but smaller ring at the rear of the lens that you can unscrew as well.

Don't do it unless you A) know what you're doing or B) don't care about reassembling the lens in a useable form.

Comment: Thank you very much! This lens was in the scrap bin so I am not interested in reassembling it!